# Why was my Unclear What You're Asking flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455263/how-to-generate-4-random-non-repeating-numbers-from-0-9) not because the title was unclear, but because the body was.

I made an answer that generated 4 random numbers from 0 to 9, just as the guy asked *in the title*. The body is quite unclear (at least to me) - he pushes, pops, some values are not correct, some are repeating. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455294/3130281) got downvoted almost immediately. Eventually, the guy picked *it* as the correct one. That happened after I edited it in such a way that it no longer generated 4 numbers. It removed 4 random values from an array and added them to another array.

Judging by what he picked as correct, I can say that what he wanted to do is `store 4 randomly removed values from an array` and not `generate 4 random non-repeating numbers` - what he actually asked. If you ask for something that you don't actually need, isn't that unclear?

---

If in the answer ***he picked as correct*** you fill the array with these values:

```
[42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
```

You would get the output `[42, 42, 42, 42]`. Those are four not random, not in the range 0-9 and *definitely not* non-repeating numbers.

The title of the question is:

> How to generate 4 random non-repeating numbers from 0-9?

And what he basically deems as valid output is `[42, 42, 42, 42]`.

### How was that clear?

Comment: To answer your title: because 3 users selected to leave open in the close queue https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15337279

Comment: If the body of the question is unclear, you should ask clarifying questions in the comments before answering.

Comment: I had he same issue with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422918/square-root-to-2-decimal-places By the time the flag was actually evaluated, the user edited their post and my flag was incorrectly declined